# Installing Ubuntu gets stuck during installation

Tags: usb-installation

Image where installation stops:

[image]

so I have been trying to install ubuntu on my pc, it has a amd fx 6300 processor, 8 gb RAM, and gtx 970 GPU. It keeps getting stuck here.